# php artisan serve, composer update/install .. nothing working suddenly

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

Everything was working fine, and then i restarted my system(OS X Yosemite), none of the artisan or composer commands are working now. php -v shows fine. But other commands just move to the next line without doing anything.

What did i do?

Comment: You running the commands from your project root?

Comment: Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Run `which composer` and see if it's in your $PATH.

Comment: yes running commands from project root, tried different projects, even tried creating new laravel project, even that command doesnt work. Laravel version 4.2

Comment: I'm to familiar with 4.2. Can't help you. Good luck!

Comment: Are you using laravel homestead?

Answer (score 0):

check your port 8000 if it has been used

try this command: php artisan serve --port="8888"

Answer (score 0):

Updated my php, changed path in bashprofile using `sudo nano .bash_profile`

and everything works fine.